# How to save variable in string in controller and pass it into view in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I have method in which I grab all data from db and pass it to the view. That's ok, and then in view I can `$location->ip` (for grabbing location from that specific user), but I'm trying to fetch string in controller, put it in this variable

```
$location = GeoIP::getLocation($getIp);
```

and then pass that variable in view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [View::share()](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views) to make your variable available in all your view files. Just do this :

```
View::share('location ', GeoIP::getLocation($getIp));
```

Now you can access your `location` variable within any view you wish via the `$location` variable.

Comment: I know for this, but problem is in this $getIP, because i need every IP associated with user id

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your problem. Can you be more specific please.

Comment: It's complicated to specify, but i did something different, i have save it like array.